# Python SIP expose function

Tags: c++, python, python-sip

I'm writing a Python module for some C++ code using SIP. However whilst I can easily expose classes, I cannot find a way to expose standalone functions.

Here is my header file defining the functions that I wish to expose to Python: *ProxySettings.h*

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Wininet.h>

bool SetConnectionOptions(const char * proxy_full_addr);
bool DisableConnectionProxy();
```

And here is my attempt at my SIP file so far: *ProxySettings.sip*. Currently running *sip.exe* generates C++ code with no problems, but when I come to compile it, the compiler complains about missing identifiers *SetConnectionOptions* and *DisableConnectionProxy*.

```
%Module ieproxy 0

bool SetConnectionOptions(const char * proxy_full_addr);
bool DisableConnectionProxy();
```

I think that I have to use a directive to include the *ProxySettings.h* header file into my SIP file, but I am not sure what directive to use. %TypeHeaderCode which is what you use for a class doesn't work with just a function.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
%Module ieproxy 0  

%UnitCode
#include <ProxySettings.h>
%End

bool SetConnectionOptions(const char * proxy_full_addr); 
bool DisableConnectionProxy();
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me
 inline`mingw32-make install

 makefile:26: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '.c.o'
copy /y learn.pyd C:\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\learn.pyd
        1 file(s) copied.
strip C:\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\learn.pyd


learn>python
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

>>> import learn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`